# Where are letsencrypt publicly logged ips?

Tags: https, lets-encrypt, certbot

When setting up https certificates with letsencrypt/certbot (i.e. `sudo certbot certonly --manual` as explained [here](https://medium.com/@franxyzxyz/setting-up-free-https-with-heroku-ssl-and-lets-encrypt-80cf6eac108e)), it says

```
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
NOTE: The IP of this machine will be publicly logged as having requested this certificate. If you're running certbot in manual mode on a machine that is not your server, please ensure you're okay with that.

Are you OK with your IP being logged?
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
(Y)es/(N)o:
```

If you don't agree

```
Cleaning up challenges
Must agree to IP logging to proceed
```

My question is where are these ips publicly logged to ?

Comment: [Those are not publicly available at the moment](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/public-ip-logging/26385/6), but I don't what that information to be logged by anyone anyway. Do you know of a way to bypass that step?

Comment: @rraallvv I didn't find a way to bypass it easily. I was doing it for a client who did not want their IP logged, so I ended up starting a VM and doing it all from there. A very clunky workaround, but it worked. I'm sure there are easier ways